# Find all functions $f$ with this property,

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Let $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$ be given by

$$\sum_{d\mid n} f(d) = \phi(n)$$

where $\phi(n)$ is the Euler function, and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Find all such $f$.

Any hints are welcome.  If you wish to post an answer, please only post hints, especially if they are conceptual / fundamental hints regarding elementary number theory or abstract algebra.

**My work:**

I know that the Euler function $\phi(n)$ counts the number of positive integers up to and including $n$ that is coprime to $n$, that is, $\gcd(k,n) = 1$ for $1\le k \le n$.

So I know that $\phi(1) =1$, $\phi(2)=1$, $\phi(3)=2$, $\phi(4)=2$, $\phi(5) = 4$, $\phi(6) =3$, $\phi(7)=6$ ...

And I observe that, for $n$ prime, I have the pattern:

$$\phi(n) = (n-1)$$

Also, the Euler function is multiplicative so that $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$

whenever $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

And $$\sum_{d|m} \phi(d) = m$$

How could I proceed from here?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you heard of something called Mobius Inversion?

Comment: Hi @Ravi, nope, so I'd rather not use extra machinery / theorems for now, if possible...

Comment: Okay, im not sure how to do it without inversion, but it will be useful for you to investigate $\phi(n)$ for $n$ a prime, next $n$ a prime power and see what sort of patterns emerge.

Comment: To say that $f$ is "given by" something is not the right phrasing if the information doesn't actually determine $f$.  And you seem to suggest that it doesn't. Or at least that you're refusing to assume it does.  I might have said "Find all functions $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb C$ that satisfy$$ \sum_{d\,\mid\,n} f(d) = \varphi(n),$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function." $\qquad$

Comment: Hi @Ravi, interesting ... I just noticed that $\phi(n) = (n-1)$ ... not a huge surprise but actually there is some pattern now...

Comment: Note that $\phi(6)=2$ and not $3$.

Comment: Maybe if you suppose that such a function exists you can find its value on certain numbers? What must $f(1)$ be? What should $f(p)$, where $p$ is a prime, be? What should $f(pq)$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, be? You will need to discover more about the Euler function in order to continue in this way. If $p$ is a prime, $n$ is a positive integer and $k$ is a positive integer such the $\gcd(k,p^n) \neq 1$ what can you say about $k$? How many such $k$'s are there?

Comment: Hi @Nex, thanks for your comment; so construct a piecewise-defined $f$?  I will try that now.  It may be my best move - perhaps even the *right* move, without applying the mobius inversion theorem, which would seem to answer the question in one line, which I don't believe is the point of the problem (yet)...

Comment: What I meant is that if you find the value of $f$ on certain numbers you might notice a pattern.